# Why doesn't this jQuery click event work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, event-handling

I have a div with class name `profile-activity-box` which comes as a AJAX response (html code). The AJAX part works perfectly, so no problem there. With 'works' I mean that the div is displayed correctly. Now when I put a click event on it, it doesn't work. I can't figure out what goes wrong. This is the code:

```
<div class="row-fluid main-div"> 

    <h3 class="offset1">Laatste activiteit</h3>
    <div class="span8 offset1" id="activity-box-wrapper"></div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var id = <?php echo $user['User']['id']?>;
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: '/users/getCheckins',
                data: "id="+id,
                success: function(resp) {
                    //console.log(resp);
                    $('#activity-box-wrapper').html(resp);
                },

                error: function(e) {
                    console.log("Server said (error):\n '" + e + "'");
                }
        });
            // this works! So the element is defined!
        console.log($('.profile-activity-box')); 
            // but this does not !
        $('.profile-activity-box').on('click',function(){ 
            $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
            console.log("hello!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the AJAX response before someone asks me to post it:

```
echo "<div class='profile-activity-box'>";
echo "<div class='span6'>";
echo "<img src='/img/gf80x80.jpg' alt='' />";
echo $value['Game']['title'];
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='span3 offset3' style='padding: 30px;'> ";
echo "<img src='/img/thumbsup.png' alt='likes' />";
echo "<span class='like-count'> 2 </span>";
echo "<img src='/img/messagebubble.png' alt='comments'". 
      "style='padding-left:30px' />"; 
echo "<span class='comment-count'> 4</span>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<textarea style='display:none;' class='profile-comment-box' rows='3'".
     "placeholder='plaats een comment :)'></textarea>";
```

Once again, this whole thing is displayed correctly and is also defined at the time I use the click event. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You are using the incorrect syntax for .on to get event delegation. Please see the documentation (or one of the other hundred duplicate questions) http://api.jquery.com/on/ Here's a tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to bind an `on` event on a dom element which currently does not exist. As @InTry answered below you need to bind an event on a parent/root which already exists in the DOM at the time of binding. And then you scope it using the className as the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add handlers to elements already available.

But your `.profile-activity-box` is not there before ajax response.

To overcome, this situation, we use jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

We apply handler to already present parent element (`#activity-box-wrapper` in this case)  and when we click at parent, we check if that was on `.profile-activity-box` too.

```
$('#activity-box-wrapper').on('click','.profile-activity-box',function(){ // but this does not !
    $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
    console.log("hello!");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('#activity-box-wrapper').on('click', '.profile-activity-box', function(){ 
     $(this).next().slideToggle(100);           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
 $('.profile-activity-box').on('click',function(){
```

to this -

```
 $('body').on('click', '.profile-activity-box', function(){
```

To use the event delagation mode of on() - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the event to the nearest parent that is present in the dom when this code is executed:

```
       $('#activity-box-wrapper').on('click','.profile-activity-box',function(){ // but this does not !
            $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
            console.log("hello!");
        });
```